# How to Querying Db certain seconds untill get result in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-jpa

I Want to Call **repository.findbyId(id)** untill get result with certain seconds.

*Ex: select employee detail where id =1 continuously 25 seconds.  If we get result at 15th second we have to stop our call.*

I tried with **@Retryable** but it not suitable for my case.

We can achieve this by **Awaitility.await().atMost(20,   TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollInterval(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.untilAsserted()}**

But, we can use Awaitility for testing assert only. Is there any other option available instead of Awaitility in spring boot?

Comment: Why specifically can't you use Awaitility? I just deployed an update to my Boot application pulling it in for runtime.

Comment: That's a very strange use case. 2 seconds is an eternity in Cassandra. I'm really curious as to why you need to wait. Perhaps if you provide some background on what problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to give a better answer. Cheers!

Comment: @chrylis As per code standard, Awaitility for testing purpose only. Development side we need find some alternative

Answer (score -1):

`spring-retry` should have all you need. Even if the annotation-based API with `@Retryable` is not suitable, spring-retry also has programmatic retry with `RetryTemplate` (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry#retrytemplate) in which every detail can be configured.

You could also write a retry mechanism yourself. Per your description you don't need much more than a loop with `Thread.sleep()` and some timer/counter. Awaitility and spring-retry also just use `Thread.sleep()`, but it just looks much more complicated because they are so highly configurable (which you don't need).

Comment: as per our coding standards we should not use Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: Well look into Awaitility and spring-retry code and you will see Thread.sleeps. Also other clients that I know (non-reactive) use Thread.sleep, e.g Feign: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/Retryer.java#L73 If you don't want sleeps then you need to implement a timer and some kind of wait/notify system. For that I don't have an answer/solution ready for you.

Comment: A question to clarify: Are you not allowed to use Thread.sleep speficically, or are you generally not allowed to block a thread for longer time?